# sympy: function to convert string into actual sympy object

Tags: csv, sympy, string-conversion

assume I have a csv-file in the following format:

```
csc($0);\csc@@{$0};1;;;;;https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#csc
cot($0);\cot@@{$0};1;;;;;https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#cot
> ;;;;;;;
sinh($0);\sinh@@{$0};1;;;;;https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sinh
```

I want to read it into a Python script using:

```
default_semantic_latex_table = {}
with open("CAS_SymPy.csv") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
        for line in reader:
            if line[0] != '':
                tup = (line[0], line[2])
                default_semantic_latex_table[tup] = str(line[1])
```

I'd like to get a dict of the following form: default_semantic_latex_table = {
(sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric.sinh, 1): FormatTemplate(r"\sinh@{$0}")}

The first element of the tuple should not be a string but an actual sympy-object.

Does anyone know about a function that can convert a string into a sympy-object such as `sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric.sin`, `sympy.functions.elementary.exponential.exp` or `sympy.concrete.products.Product`? I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

`sympify` converst strings to SymPy objects:

```py
>>> from sympy import sympify, pi
>>> sympify('cos')
cos
>>> _(pi)
-1
```

Comment: Thank you! The issue here is that sympify also tries to parse the `$0` which hence throws an error. Is there a way to just parse the expression without the dollarsign-arguments?

Comment: Can you replace `$0` with `x`? Then it will parse `cos(x)` and if you just want the `cos` part you can use the `func` attribute, e.g. `sympify('cos(x)').func`.

Comment: Thanks! This works almost for every test expression except for the diff function. (I set evaluate to False): `sympy.sympify('diff(cos(x), x)')` returns `Piecewise((x, Eq(1, 0)), (1, Eq(1, 1)), (0, True))*(-sin(x))` and `print(sympy.sympify('diff(x, x)').func)` returns Piecewise. Is it generally not possible to sympify the diff function such that it returns a `sympy.core.function.Derivative` object?

Comment: You can replace "diff(" with "Derivative(" which is the unevaluated form of the derivative.